# Does assigning icon to a .net library assembly has any use

Tags: .net, dll, icons, assemblies

Right now I am working on a dll project with several handy .net tools. Updating an assembly version I have noticed that I could also provide an icon for an assembly.

Having icon on a Console, WPF or WinForms application makes sense since it will be displayed in a lot of spots - UAC warnings, takbar, customized task manages, etc.

But if I assign an icon to an assembly, that is going to be compiled into a .dll file, will it be displayed anywhere in the system?

Comment: DLLs can have a use a resource-only repository.  Used that way in .NET too, satellite DLLs.  But that's not what you are talking about, Windows can only deal with icon as *unmanaged* resources.  Having more than one requires a .res file.  And that's pretty pointless for a DLL, Windows looks in the EXE for icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't assign an icon (to be displayed) into a dll.

Have you thought about maybe registering a different extension for the file into the executable that will be hosting it. Then when you compile have a post build step that renames the file to "myoncewas.dll" "myoncewas.customextension" then within your code instead of normal load methods for the dll, dynamically load the dll instead using the "myoncewas.customextension", then your files will show with the Icon that you have registered for .customextension.

Maybe this is making it more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't need it since it is a NuGet distributed library. If It was for a part of a project - doing .extension with icons would be very neat. Thanks for the idea.